# Enter a Class Actions to a dictionary

Tags: c#, function, dictionary

I tried to create a function that insert all 'LIbrary' function into a dictionary.
There isn't a function in 'LIbrary' that gets a parameter.

---

```
    class Menu
{
    LIbrary ibrary = new LIbrary();
    public Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, Action>> ddictionary;
    public Menu() { ddictionary = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, Action>>(); }

    public void InsertToADictAllTheFunctionsOfAClass()
    {
        var methods = ibrary.GetType().GetMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
        {
            ddictionary.Add(ddictionary.Count + 1, new Tuple<string, Action>(methods[i].Name, () => methods[i].Invoke(ibrary, Array.Empty<object>())));
        }
    }

    public void PrintMenu()
    {
        foreach(var item in ddictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} - {item.Value.Item1}");
        }
    }

    public void ChooseAnOptionFromDict()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter answer");
        int answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (ddictionary.ContainsKey(answer))
            ddictionary[answer].Item2.Invoke();
    }
}
```

---

[image]

[image]

---

Why I have this error?

Comment: So how can I do that function?

Comment: I did'nt understant you well..
'LIbrary is a class with a functions.
I want to insert that functions into a dictionry, I don't want to invoked them yet..

Comment: I will let the user an option to choose which function to use. For example:
I will print to the console:
1 - Add Book To Library
and if the user press 1 - then the "AddBookToLibrary" will play.

Comment: @Llama : It is the only way of going.  Forget that it is an Action.  The OP only wants to get a list of functions in a class.

Comment: @Llama : What method beside reflection that gives a name of all the methods in a class dynamically?  You first need the names of the methods before you can add them to the dictionary.

Comment: @Llama : Read the question "create a function that insert all 'LIbrary' function into a dictionary"

Comment: I didn't understand what both of you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look as a good practice to do it this way but I guess you'd like to do something like this

```cs
class Menu
{
    LIbrary ibrary = new LIbrary();
    public Menu() { }
    public void InsertToADictAllTheFunctionsOfAClass()
    {
        // int => key, string => Action.Name, Action => Action
        var ddictionary = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, Action>>();
        var methods = ibrary.GetType().GetMethods();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
        {
            ddictionary.Add(ddictionary.Count + 1, new Tuple<string, Action>(methods[i].Name, () => methods[i].Invoke(library, Array.Empty<object>())));
        }
    }
}
```

Although this can throw you exceptions when Library class contains a method accepting any arguments and you'll try to invoke it.

Comment: I have an exeption that says "No overload for method "invoke" takes 0 arguments"

Comment: Anyway, just as a reminder, I'd stay away from reflection as long as possible and try to use good OOP practices like interfaces and other patterns rather than using reflection to obtain methods etc. Unless you really have to do it or just want to learn how it works.

Comment: I update my post after I fixed my code, can you help me with this error?
And what better way I have to solve it?